# Moving the second column to first column using awk

Tags: bash, awk, row

I would like do the following using awk:

Example of my input data with four columns and a number of rows:

```
10 20 30 40
50 30 60 80
90 12 40 20
```

Desired output:

```
10 20
30 40
>
50 30 
60 80
>
90 12 
40 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
awk '{print $1 " "  $2 "\n" $3 " " $4 "\n>"}'
```

output is:

```
10 20
30 40
>
50 30
60 80
>
90 12
40 20
>
```

Sorry about the trailing >

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. In fact I need the tailing to be included.

Answer (score 1):

Try `awk '{ print $1" "$2"\n" $3" "$4"\n>" }'`

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -r 's/(\S+\s+){2}/&\n/;$!a >' file
```

```
10 20
30 40
>
50 30
60 80
>
90 12
40 20
```

Notice the last line, no unwanted trailing `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I add a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution (w/o calling any external utilities):

Script:

```
while read a b c d; do echo -e "$a $b\n$c $d\n>"; done <infile
```

Or without the explicit loop:

```
printf "%s %s\n%s %s\n>\n" $(<infile)
```

Input:

```
cat >infile <<XXX
10 20 30 40
50 30 60 80
90 12 40 20
XXX
```

Output:

```
10 20
30 40
>
50 30
60 80
>
90 12
40 20
>
```